# How can I make time ranges for an iCal calendar from a database of entries?

Tags: macos, perl, calendar, metaprogramming, icalendar

I've got some Perl script that I'm using to scrape calendar events. I've got a database of events, and now I'd like to process these into an iCal file. I opened my university's academic iCal calendar and got the following:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
X-WR-TIMEZONE;VALUE=TEXT:America/Los_Angeles
PRODID:-//MMISoftware\, //MMISoftware//EN
X-WR-CALNAME;VALUE=TEXT:spring14cal
X-WR-RELCALID;VALUE=TEXT:87FB4C57-1D7B-4B80-B200-AEED845CB3AF
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
SEQUENCE:1
UID:41D26C6E-965B-4BFB-AEC0-F1614074A4AF
DTSTAMP:20140127T111052Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20140101
SUMMARY:FAFSA
DESCRIPTION:First day to obtain FAFSA financial aid applications for 201
 4-15 academic year online at http://www.fafsa.ed.gov
DURATION:P1D
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
SEQUENCE:1
UID:DFE257FB-F475-43C2-9AEB-569EC4BA321D
DTSTAMP:20140127T111052Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20140106
SUMMARY:CA Dream
DESCRIPTION:First day to obtain California Dream Act financial aid appli
 cations for 2014-15 academic year online at https://dream.csac.ca.gov
.
.
.
.
```

I see a start date, end date, and a time stamp, but I don't see a range... Not sure how to use my existing database to make an iCal file---you know, metaprogramming---with time ranges like the following:

http://musformation.com/pics/thg_sync_apple_ical.jpg

Comment: Do a search for modules made for this purpose: [`metacpan iCal`](https://metacpan.org/search?q=ical)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Date::ICal`](http://p3rl.org/Date%3a%3aICal) to format the duration strings.

The duration itself ( in your case we can see only the duration of the first event, because the duration of the second event would be the first line you skipped ) is `DURATION:P1D`, where `P1D` is the Duration itself and `DURATION` is the property name.

Further information about ICals `Duration` can be found [`here`](http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/duration.html).

When you want to parse `ICal` files, you can use [`ICal::Parser`](http://p3rl.org/iCal%3a%3aParser).

Creating `ICal` Files can be done easily with [`Data::ICal`](http://p3rl.org/Data%3a%3aICal). An example:

```
use Data::ICal;
use Data::ICal::Entry::Event;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $calendar = Data::ICal->new;

my $vtodo = Data::ICal::Entry::Event->new;
$vtodo->add_properties(
  summary => "read SO",
  description => "reading cool SO posts",
  dtstart => Date::ICal->new( 
    day => 4, 
    month => 6, 
    year => 2014,
    hour => 8,
    min => 30,
    sec => 00
  )->ical,
  dtend => Date::ICal->new(
    day => 5, 
    month => 6, 
    year => 2014,
    hour => 9,
    min => 50,
    sec => 00
  )->ical,
);
$calendar->add_entry($vtodo);
print $calendar->as_string;
```